# git svn clone without knowing the svn layout

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I am doing SVN to Git migration and for which when I use `git svn clone` command, I need to mention the `--stdlayout` option. My query is as an admin I should not be concerned about the layout of SVN. So is there any way how I can use `git svn clone` command without knowing the SVN layout.

What I am using now if SVN has a standard layout:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt <svn-repo>/<project> <git-repo-name>
```

if not standard layout:

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk --branches=/branches --branches=/bugfixes --tags=/tags --authors-file=authors.txt <svn-repo>/<project> <git-repo-name>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this about one-time migration and then only Git is used, or do you want to commit back to SVN from your Git clone?

Comment: @Vampire No this has to be a complete migration, after the migration no one can commit on svn as it will be made  read only.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Yes I get your point. I have already implemented the migration with git-svn though I havent tried it with complex histories. Though when after migration I host it somewhere like on bitbucket, github or gitlab, I can see everything that is the history, the branches, the tags and also I am able to commit new changes. Maybe what you are suggesting is preferable if we have complex histories. Can you please tell me what do you mean when you say "complex history"? As I able to retain the history for now.

Comment: Also it has been documented on the official atlassian page for the migration of svn to git codebase. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview

Comment: The "official" Atlassian page is just a tutorial those guys provide and that is made for the broad mass, as it is easier to start with. Or they just don't know any better. Besides that their tutorial afair also contains fixing *some* of the drawbacks of git-svn like moving down the tags and others after the actual cloning. The KDE `svn2git` is always preferable over `git-svn` in my opinion, even for the simplest histories. If not for anyhting else, then because it is a gazillion times faster and more stable.